# Playing song using processing.sound.*;

Tags: processing

Trying to play a song in processing. The song is in the program's data file and the processing sound library is installed.

Code -

```
import processing.sound.*;

// A Sample object (for a sound)
SoundFile song;

void setup() {
  size(480, 270);
  song = new SoundFile(this, "test.mp3");
  song.play();
}

void draw() {
}
```

Error shown is - NullPointerException.

Comment: double check if the file `test.mp3` is exists in the sketch folder or in the sketch's data folder. (you might see another message in console like "Error: Soundfile doesn't exist. Pleae check path")

Comment: It's in the sketch's data folder

Comment: Can you try `song = new SoundFile(this, dataPath("test.mp3"));` ?

Comment: Still showing NullPointerException error.

Comment: weird, maybe there's a problem decoding that particular file ? 1: does **Processing > Examples > Libraries > Sound > Soundfile > Sample** work for you ? 2. can you export the same sound as a .wav file (unsigned 16 bit, 44100 Hz) (maybe with Audacity or a similar tool) and try loading that instead of the .mp3 ?

Comment: Worked when I changed the file to to a wav. Thank you so much.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I've added the comment above as an answer so it can be easily found when others experience the same issue (and also make it easy to vote up and/or mark the answer if was helpful). Out curiosity, would it be easy to share the audio properties of the mp3 you had ? (perhaps it was 48KHz instead of 44.1 KHz or a strange compression bitrate ?)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the path to the audio file and if the path is valid double check audio file itself.

There are many encoding presets and maybe not all of them are supported by the Processing sound library.

To be on the safe side try exporting your audio file as an unsigned 16 bit, 44100 Hz uncompressed wav file (from a DAW tool like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or similar)